# Bulk insert and update in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GRN_id] => 1
            [flag_status] => 1
            [array_indv_count] => 0
            [qty] => 1
            [location_RejHoldCmt] => 
            [user_id] => 5
            [date] => 29-Jul-2020
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [GRN_id] => 1
            [flag_status] => 1
            [array_indv_count] => 1
            [qty] => 
            [location_RejHoldCmt] => 
            [user_id] => 5
            [date] => 29-Jul-2020
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [GRN_id] => 2
            [flag_status] => 3
            [array_indv_count] => 2
            [qty] => 0
            [location_RejHoldCmt] => 
            [user_id] => 5
            [date] => 29-Jul-2020
        )

)
```

This array is passing to the controller for insertion/updation:

```
    $count = count($_POST['flag_status']);
        for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $data[] = array(
                'GRN_id'=>$_POST['id'],
                'flag_status' => $_POST['flag_status'][$i],
                'array_indv_count' => $i,
                'qty' => $_POST['qty'][$i],
                'location_RejHoldCmt' => $_POST['location_RejHoldCmt'][$i],
                'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata('userid'),
                'date'=>date('d-M-Y'),
            );
        }
$this->db->insert_batch('GRN_details', $data);
```

I need to update the DB if the rows exists in the array based on the three values(GRN_id,flag_status,array_indv_count) and insert if no matches with the same three values. Now the rows are inserting into the db on every execution. My DB structure is like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting as a batch, check for each record if it exists according to the conditions. If a record exists according to the conditions update that record else insert as a new record.

```
$count = count($_POST['flag_status']);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $data = array(
        'GRN_id'=>$_POST['id'],
        'flag_status' => $_POST['flag_status'][$i],
        'array_indv_count' => $i,
        'qty' => $_POST['qty'][$i],
        'location_RejHoldCmt' => $_POST['location_RejHoldCmt'][$i],
        'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata('userid'),
        'date'=>date('d-M-Y'),
    );
    $data = xss_clean($data);

    // select from table with conditions
    $this->db->select('id')
    $this->db->from('GRN_details')
    $this->db->where('GRN_id', $data['GRN_id']);
    $this->db->where('flag_status', $data['flag_status']);
    $this->db->where('array_indv_count', $data['array_indv_count']);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        // if there is a match update
        $record = $query->row();
        $this->db->update('GRN_details', $data, array('id'=> $record->id ));
    } else {
        // if there is no match insert
        $this->db->insert('GRN_details', $data);
    }
}
```